# nls - convergence error

Tags: r, nls, convergence

## For this dataset:

```
dat = structure(list(x = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L), 
y = c(2.2, 2.2, 1.95, 1.9, 4.1, 3.95, 3.75, 3.4, 5.15, 4.6, 
4.75, 5.15, 3.7, 4.1, 3.9, 3.5, 7, 6.7, 6.7, 6.95, 4.95, 6, 6.45, 
6.4, 7, 4.45, 6.15, 6.4, 7, 6.6, 6.7, 7, 4.5, 4.7, 5.75, 4.35, 
5.4, 5.15, 5.7, 5.7, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("x", "y"), 
row.names = c(6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 38L, 39L, 
40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L), 
class = "data.frame")
```

Where "x" is the **temperature** and "y" is the response variable of a **biological process**

I'm trying to fit this function

```
beta.reg<-function(x, Yopt,Tmin,Topt,Tmax, b1) {
Yopt*((x-Tmin)/(Topt-Tmin))^(b1*(Topt-Tmin)/(Tmax-Topt))*((Tmax-x) / (Tmax-Topt)) ^ b1
}

mod <- nls(y ~ beta.reg(x, Yopt,Tmin,Topt,Tmax, b1), data=dat,
       start=c(Yopt=6, Tmin=0.1, Topt=24, Tmax=30, b1=1),
       control=nls.control(maxiter=800))
```

But, I'm having this message error:

> Error en numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
>   Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model

I've tried the same function with another similar dataset and fits correctly...

```
 rnorm<-(10)
 y <- c(20,60,70,49,10)
 rnorm<-(10)
 y <- c(20,60,70,49,10)
 dat<-data.frame(x = rep(c(15,20,25,30,35), times=5),
              rep = as.factor(rep(1:5, each=5)),
              y = c(y+rnorm(5), y+rnorm(5),y+rnorm(5),y+rnorm(5),y+rnorm(5)))
```

Could someone help me with this?

Session Info:

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] nlme_3.1-118        latticeExtra_0.6-26 RColorBrewer_1.0-5  lattice_0.20-29    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.1.1  tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: Is this in R? If so, then you should add the [tag:R] tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are so many problems here that I doubt it can be covered adequately in an SO post, but this should get you started.

First, it looks like you want `Tmax < max(dat$x)`, e.g., < 35. This causes a problem because then `Tmax - x < 0` for some values of `x` and when you try to raise a negative number to a power (in the second term of your formula), you get `NA`'s. This is the cause of the error message.

Second, convergence of a non-linear model depends on the model formula and also the data, so the fact that the process converges with one set of data but not another is completely irrelevant.

Third, non-linear modelling iteratively minimizes the residual sum of squares as a function of the parameters. If the RSS surface has  **local minima**, and your `start` is close to one, the algorithms will find it. But only the **global minimum** is the true solution. Your problem has many, many local minima.

Fourth, `nls(...)` uses the Gauss Newton method by default. Gauss Newton is notoriously unstable with shifting parameters (parameters which are added to or subtracted from the predictor, so `Tmin` and `Tmax` in your case). Fortunately, the `minpak.lm` package implements the Levenberg Marquardt method, which is much more stable under these conditions. The `nlsLM(...)` function in that package uses the same calling sequence as `nls(...)` and returns and object of type `nls`, so all the methods for that class of object work as well. Use that.

Fifth, a fundamental assumption in non-linear regression (in fact all least-squares regression) is that the residuals are normally distributed. So you have to validate any solution using a Q-Q plot.

Sixth, your model has a perverse set of characteristics. When `Tmin -> -Inf` the first term in the model approaches `1`. It turns out that this yields a lower RSS than any other value of `Tmin` less than `min(dat$x)`, so the algorithms all tend to drive `Tmin` to large negative values. You can see this easily as follows:

```
library(minpack.lm)
mod <- nlsLM(y ~ beta.reg(x, Yopt,Tmin,Topt,Tmax, b1), data=dat,
             start=c(Yopt=6,Tmin=0,Topt=24,Tmax=50, b1=1),
             control=nls.lm.control(maxiter=1024,maxfev=1024))
coef(summary(mod))
#         Estimate   Std. Error     t value     Pr(>|t|)
# Yopt    6.347019    0.2919686 21.73870235 8.055342e-25
# Tmin -155.530098 2204.0011003 -0.07056716 9.440694e-01
# Topt   21.157545    0.6702713 31.56564484 2.240134e-31
# Tmax   35.000000   11.4838614  3.04775537 3.933164e-03
# b1      3.321326    9.1844548  0.36162468 7.194035e-01
sum(residuals(mod)^2)
# [1] 50.24696

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(y~x,dat)
with(as.list(coef(mod)),curve(beta.reg(x, Yopt,Tmin,Topt,Tmax, b1),add=TRUE))
qqnorm(residuals(mod))
```

[image]

This looks like a pretty decent fit **but it isn't**: the Q-Q plot shows that the residuals are not remotely normal. The fact that both `Tmin` and `b1` are very poorly estimated, and the value for `Tmin` is not physically meaningful, are problems with the data, not the fit.

Seventh, it turns out that the fit above is actually a **local minimum**. We can see this by doing a grid search on `Tmin`, `Tmax`, and `b1` (leaving out `Yopt` and `Topt` to save time, and because these parameters are well estimated regardless of the starting point).

```
init <- c(Yopt=6, Topt=24)
grid <- expand.grid(Tmin= seq(0,4,len=100),
                    Tmax= seq(35,100,len=10),
                    b1  = seq(1,10,len=10))
mod.lst <- apply(grid,1,function(gr){
  nlsLM(y ~ beta.reg(x, Yopt,Tmin,Topt,Tmax, b1), data=dat,
        start=c(init,gr),control=nls.control(maxiter=800)) })
rss <- sapply(mod.lst,function(m)sum(residuals(m)^2))
mod <- mod.lst[[which.min(rss)]]   # fit with lowest RSS
coef(summary(mod))
#        Estimate   Std. Error      t value     Pr(>|t|)
# Yopt   6.389238    0.2534551 25.208557840 2.177168e-27
# Topt  22.636505    0.5605621 40.381798589 7.918438e-36
# Tmin  35.000002  104.6221159  0.334537316 7.396005e-01
# Tmax  36.234602  133.4987344  0.271422809 7.873647e-01
# b1   -41.512912 7552.0298633 -0.005496921 9.956395e-01
sum(residuals(mod)^2)
# [1] 34.24019

plot(y~x,dat)
with(as.list(coef(mod)),curve(beta.reg(x, Yopt,Tmin,Topt,Tmax, b1),add=TRUE))
qqnorm(residuals(mod))
```

[image]

Mathematically, this is a distinctly superior fit: RSS is lower and the residuals are much more nearly normally distributed. Again, the fact that the parameters are not well estimated, and are not physically meaningful, is a problem with the data (and perhaps the model formula), not the fitting process.

All of the foregoing suggests that there is something wrong with your model. One problem with it, mathematically, is that the function is undefined for `x` outside of `(Tmin,Tmax)`. Since you have data out to `x=35`, the fitting algorithm will never yield `Tmax < 35` (if it converges). An approach to deal with this changes your model function slightly to clip to 0 outside that range. (I have no idea if this is legitimate based on the physics of your problem, though...).

```
beta.reg<-function(x, Yopt,Tmin,Topt,Tmax, b1) {
  ifelse(x>Tmax,0,
    ifelse(x<Tmin,0,
      Yopt*((x-Tmin)/(Topt-Tmin))^(b1*(Topt-Tmin)/(Tmax-Topt))*((Tmax-x) / (Tmax-Topt)) ^ b1
  ))
}
```

Running the code above with this function yields:

```
coef(summary(mod))
#         Estimate   Std. Error     t value     Pr(>|t|)
# Yopt   6.1470413   0.21976766   27.970636 3.202940e-29
# Tmin -52.8172658 184.16899439   -0.286787 7.756528e-01
# Topt  23.0777898   0.63750721   36.200045 7.638121e-34
# Tmax  30.0039413   0.02529877 1185.984187 1.038918e-98
# b1     0.5966129   0.32439982    1.839128 7.280793e-02

sum(residuals(mod)^2)
# [1] 28.10144

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(y~x,dat)
with(as.list(coef(mod)),curve(beta.reg(x, Yopt,Tmin,Topt,Tmax, b1),add=TRUE))
qqnorm(residuals(mod))
qqline(residuals(mod))
```

[image]

In fact the grid search yields exactly the same result independent of starting point. Note that RSS is lower than any of the results with the earlier model, and that `b1` is much better estimated (and *very* different from the estimate with the earlier model function). The residuals are still not normal, but in this case I would want to inspect the data for outliers.

Comment: Great @jlhoward! I also think that the dataset has many problems, but it's biology... I'll coment every point of your reply: 1st- Obviously if I test temperatures >30°c will have a response of around 0. I thought about excludying the 35°C point, to have a `Tmax < max(x)`; 2nd- I just give a second example to show that th function really works and give an idea of the curve shape; 4th- I didn't really know that package, it's look good! 6th-In future experiments I'll include T°C lowers to avoid that kind of errors `Tmin < min(dat$x)`

Comment: Your last model seems to have the best biological sense, without considering `Tmin`. I think, It will be difficult to estimate `Tmin` with this model and dataset. What do you think about fitting a linear model with a subset of x's < Topt, to estimate `Tmin`? Could be a solution?

Comment: Before I did that I'd look at the data around `x ~ 17`. There's something odd about those replicates: it's hard to explain why your response there is the same as at `x ~ 10`, plus these points explain most of the deviation from normality in the residuals. You might consider excluding those replicates and refitting.

Comment: I'm having this message error when installing "minpak.lm" package:

[ Warning in install.packages :
package ‘minpak.lm’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)]

Comment: It's minpack.lm, with a ”c”.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another possible solution to the @jlhoward 's one...

I found this `nls2` package:

```
library("nls2")
```

Exludying `x~17,35` from the original dataset:

```
newdat <- subset(dat, x!=17 & x!=35 )
```

Applying the function to the reduced dataset:

```
beta.reg<-with(newdat,  
           y ~ Yopt*((x-Tmin)/(Topt-Tmin))^(b1*(Topt-Tmin)/(Tmax-Topt))*((Tmax-x) / Tmax-Topt))^b1
           )
```

Creating a set of starters:

```
st1 <- expand.grid(Yopt = seq(4, 8, len = 4),
                   Tmin = seq(0, 4, len = 4), 
                   Topt = seq(15, 25, len = 4),
                   Tmax= seq(28, 38, len = 4),
                   b1 = seq(0, 4, len = 4))
```

Fitting the model:

```
mod <- nls2(beta.reg, start = st1, algorithm = "brute-force")
```

Extracting coefficients:

```
round(coef(summary(mod)),3)

#     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# Yopt    6.667      0.394  16.925    0.000
# Tmin    0.000     12.023   0.000    1.000
# Topt   21.667      0.746  29.032    0.000
# Tmax   31.333      1.924  16.289    0.000
# b1      1.333      1.010   1.320    0.197
```

Diagnostics:

```
sum(residuals(mod)^2)

# [1] 50.18246
```

And finally, the adjusted function and the QQ-normal plot:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
with(newdat,plot(y~x,xlim=c(0,35))) 
points(fitted(mod)~I(newdat$x), pch=19)
with(as.list(coef(mod)),
 curve(
  Yopt*((x-Tmin)/(Topt-Tmin))^(b1*(Topt-Tmin)/(Tmax-Topt))*((Tmax-x) / (Tmax-Topt)) ^ b1,
   add=TRUE, col="red"))

qqnorm(residuals(mod))
qqline(residuals(mod))
```

[image]

Comment: For the record, `nls2(...)` (as you're using it) does not minimize RSS, it calculates RSS at each of the 4^5 = 1024 grid points and reports the point with the lowest RSS. This is why you get `Tmin=0`; lower values of `Tmin` will give lower RSS, but this is the lowest value in your grid.

Comment: It's true. By this way, I tried to restrict the estimated of `Tmin` to some biological sense value, sacrifying the RSS. Is this the same as the restrictions of your last model?                                   `beta.reg<-function(x, Yopt,Tmin,Topt,Tmax, b1) {`
  **`ifelse(x>Tmax,0,
     ifelse(x<Tmin,0,`**
     `Yopt*((x-Tmin)/(Topt-Tmin))^(b1*(Topt-Tmin)/(Tmax-Topt))*((Tmax-x) / (Tmax-Topt)) ^ b1
  ))
}`

Comment: No. The model above merely restricts the function to return 0 if `x` is outside the range `(Tmin,Tmax)`. It does not restrict `Tmin` or `Tmax` at all. What you've done is find the minimum RSS (more or less, it's a very coarse grid) given the chosen parameter space. This is a "best fit" in the RSS sense, but you should know that the statistics of the fit (the se values for the parameters, etc), are completely meaningless when you do it this way.

Comment: Also, all the techniques tell the same story about `Tmin` - it *cannot be accurately estimated* given your data and this model. In the last model in the other answer, `Tmin` ~ -52 +/- 360, so *it could be anything*. Notice, however, how the different approaches give very different estimate of `b1`.